# Delete a bigquery table after all the steps in dataflow job have completed

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to delete a bigquery table only after all the steps in a batch dataflow pipeline have succeeded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DataflowPipelineJob.waitToFinish(...)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowPipelineJob.html#waitUntilFinish--) to wait for your job to finish, check that the returned state was [DONE](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/PipelineResult.State.html#DONE), and then use the BigQuery API to [delete](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Table.html#delete--) the table.

Comment: This is not working if the runner is DataflowRunner. Can you please post specific samples, if the solution is still correct?